# Where to call a method to reload view on app return from background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In one of my views in a navigation controller, I have a method `- (void) loadAlert` that gets the content of a web page, parses it, and places the relevant content on a `UITextView`.  The method call is located in the `viewDidAppear:` section of my view controller.  It works fine when the view first loads and when the view appears at all when navigated to.

I also want this data load to occur when the app returns from background.  As many Stackoverflow posts and other sources indicated, I put my method call in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` :

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MainViewController *mainView = [[mainViewController alloc] init];
    [mainView loadAlert];
}
```

However, nothing occurs within the view when the app returns from background.  I expect the `UITextView` to clear, a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to spin while the content is obtained from the Internet, and the new content to be loaded into the `UITextView`.

I know that the method is being called, but nothing is happening within the view. My feeling is that the view has not yet loaded when this method is being called. **Where can I put my method call so that when the app returns from background, and if this specific view is the current view displayed in the navigation controller, it will actually refresh the UI?**

Comment: This is the wrong method. When returning from the background, you want `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, not `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` or `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, it is quite effective  to listen to these notifications anywhere in your application , you need to register your controller to one of these notification and just use your method to show whatever you want to.

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(showYourView)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

-(void) showYouView(){
 // do your stuff
}
```

**NOTE**

*Best way is to use UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification because it will only run when user comes from background to foreground, on the other hand UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification runs every time your application become active*

Comment: Simple and effective. Thank you

Comment: Except this is the wrong notification. The `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` is called far more often than just returning from the background. And don't forget to remove the observer or your app will crash at some point.

Comment: @rmaddy I did use `applicationWillEnterForeground` instead. When should I be removing the observer?

Comment: you can remove observer in `(void)dealloc` method or `(void)didRecieveMemoryWarning`, but preferabely in `dealloc`

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance of `mainViewController` rather than using the same instance which is already there. Whenever you are doing a `mainViewController *mainView = [[mainViewController alloc] init];`, it is a new instance. You should try to access the same instance which is there in the viewcontrollers stack and call this method on that.

> Where can I put my method call so that when the app returns from
>   background, and if this specific view is the current view displayed in
>   the navigation controller, it will actually refresh the UI?

Assuming that you have your UINavigationController added as a property in your appdelegate, you can use the below code in `applicationWillEnterForeground` to call loadAlert on the topViewController.

```
UIViewController *aViewController = self.navigationController.topViewController;
if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[mainViewController class]]) {
    [(mainViewController *)aViewController loadAlert];
}
```

On a side note, please start class names with capital letter. For eg:- you should have used `MainViewController` instead of `mainViewController` which normally represents a variable name.

**Update:**

If you are using the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` approach, you should add the above code in `notificationMethod` method to make sure that `mainViewController` is the current view controller which is visible. Else it could show some unexpected behaviors.

So something like this should be good:

```
- (void)notificationMethod {

   UIViewController *aViewController = self.navigationController.topViewController;
   if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[mainViewController class]]) {
      [(mainViewController *)aViewController loadAlert];
   }
}
```

Comment: @DGund, Nice to know that. Please use `UIViewController *aViewController = self.navigationController.topViewController;
 if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[mainViewController class]]) {
    [(mainViewController *)aViewController loadAlert];
}` If you want to make sure that you are not calling loadAlert when `mainViewController` is not visible. With the notification approach, you cant make sure which one is currently visible on the screen, which might cause unexpected behaviors if you dont want the screen to be refreshed when it is not visible.

Comment: Isn't this a rather convoluted approach to the problem? Isn't it much cleaner to have the actual view controller listen for the proper notification and act accordingly? Putting this logic in the app delegate really breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @rmaddy, Well, Even if he doesn't want to add this in appdelegate, this should be added in the loadAlert method to check whether that viewcontroller is currently visible. Otherwise it will cause unexpected behaviors as I mentioned above, if the topViewController is a different one.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to handle this is to have your `MainViewController` register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. Then when the notification is received, you call the `loadAlert` method.

In MainViewController.m:

```
- (void)enterForeground {
    [self loadAlert];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

You do not need to do anything in the app delegate for this. This way, the MainViewController is responsible for know what should happen and when.

Comment: You mentioned removing the observer.  I see that you are doing this in `dealloc`, but my app uses ARC.  Do I still need to?

Comment: @DGund, dealloc will be called even in ARC projects. It is just that you dont need to do release statements there.

Comment: Yes, `dealloc` is the correct place, even with ARC. I assumed ARC in my answer. Notice there is no call to `[super dealloc]`.

Comment: Yeah I thought dealloc wasn't allowed at all at first.  Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same need for a project of mine, and I had to go through the notificationCenter system to handle the matter.

First, you need to launch the notification when your application is entering foreground :

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"app_entering_foreground" object:self];
}
```

Then you need to actually listen to this particular notification where you need it.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateUI) @"app_entering_foreground" object:nil];
```

Comment: There is already a system provided notification for this: `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. There is no need to implement `applicationWillEnterForeground:` just so you can post a custom notification.

Comment: alright, didn't know that. I'll let my answer for the sake of it explaining how to throw a custom notification though.